# Should 3DS-XL get its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

In other words, is it likely to have issues that don't apply to the 3DS?

Comment: AFAIK It has slightly different specs compared to the standard 3ds in terms of battery life, weight etc. Whether or not that's justification for its own tag I don't know

Comment: As a further note, tags do not exist without a question to put them on.  In other words, you cannot create a tag by itself.  If we ever get a question where a 3DSXL tag is necessary, it can be added then.  There is no need (or way) to pre-make the tag.

Comment: @Jason ah ok, i thought that it was possible. Makes sense, though, otherwise we would have a LOT of tags :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only noteworthy differences between the two are size, battery life and the fact that the 3DS has an (annoying) LED indicating when 3D is on and the XL doesn't. I see no reason to have two tags. Other consoles have had *much* more significant differences between revisions/SKUs (slim PS3 vs 60GB fat PS3 anyone?).

I think it's quite safe to keep them both as the same tag.

Comment: [It already exists](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds-xl)

Comment: Sounds like another tag to burninate or merge to me!